# Kaplan-Meier for repeated measures in different exercise conditions

Tags: kaplan-meier

newbie here with a question:
I have a study in 40 subjects (similar amount young vs old) testing time to muscle fatigue (meaning no longer able to perform the task); each subjects performed this test at 60, 80 and 100% of muscle power, with varying succes numbers. I want to know the % that best differentiates the 2 groups (young versus old): can I use KM for this (ie can it take into account that there is no true independence in the data)? If not, can someone suggest an alternative?
Thanks a lot! Jan

Comment: I think you need to expand on some of this. For instance what do you mean by varying success numbers?

Comment: Ok, say subject 1 performed 65 successful repeats @60% but only 43 @100% and similar for all the subjects. So now I am looking for the % that best differentiates young vs old, and also as fast as possible (meaning the sooner reliable separation between groups is observed, the shorter the final test will consume time). Driving me crazy!